# Enable cross-origin resource sharing in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, cors, angular-meteor

I'm trying to get a list of channels from my main application to an external angular app.

I've added https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-rest/blob/master/packages/rest/README.md to my main meteor app and now I can get the collection with a url as json format.

Now the problem comes when I try to http request from the external angular app.

Here's what I have in my main meteor app:

```
'use strict'

Meteor.publish('channels', function (index) {
  return Channels.find({});
}, {
    url: 'channels',
    httpMethod: 'get'
});
```

and here's what I use to make the http request in the external angular app:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http.get('http://example.com/channels').then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log('success');
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log('error');
    console.log(response);
  });
```

But what I get in response is an error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/channels. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-rest/blob/master/packages/rest/README.md#cross-origin-requests) on the meteor-rest package:

> If you would like to use your API from the client side of a different app, you need to return a special header. You can do this by hooking into a method on the `simple:json-routes` package, like so:

```
// Enable cross origin requests for all endpoints
JsonRoutes.setResponseHeaders({
  "Cache-Control": "no-store",
  "Pragma": "no-cache",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
});
```

Comment: You should be able to do this in your server startup file.

Comment: that did it, just added it to the `Meteor.startup` function. Thanks for the clarification!